# change stream to java socket

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I need to change my stream of the socket by runtime.
First i need to use ObjectStreams:

```
Socket socket = ...
InputStream networkInput = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream networkOutput = socket.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(networkOutput);
oos.flush();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(networkInput);
//use the object-streams
```

Then i need to change to some other stream

```
oos.close();
ois.close();
XYOutputStream xyos = new XYOutputStream(networkOutput);
xyos.flush();
XYInputStream xyis = new XYInputStream(networkInput);
```

But if i use the upper code, the socket is closed and i get a

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

If i use

```
socket.shutdownInput();
socket.shutdownOutput();
```

instead of closing the old streams i get a

```
java.net.SocketException: interrupted data transfer (broken pipe)
```

when i try to initialize my XYStreams.

Comment: Close stream after doing all operations.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you need to close the stream.
I have written an example that uses the file system and the PrintStream, but it should be the same with a socket and your output streams.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class TestStream {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
        PrintStream p1 = new PrintStream(fos, false);
        PrintStream p2 = new PrintStream(fos, false);
        p1.print("Test");
        p1.flush();
        p2.print(100);
        p2.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried this. It works for the ObjectOutputStream but if I try to initialize the second ObjectInputStream the programm freezes. At the line new ObjectInputStream(networkInput) the program is blocking.